# Hybris Server - ERROR StatusLogger - Unable to create class de.hybris.platform.util.logging.log4j2.HybrisLog4j2LoggerContextFactory

Tags: tomcat, log4j2, sap-commerce-cloud

At the build process from the SAP hybris platform I gain the following error:

```
 [java] ERROR StatusLogger Cannot start ShutdownCallbackRegistry, already shutting down.
 [java] ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create class de.hybris.platform.util.logging.log4j2.HybrisLog4j2LoggerContextFactory specified in file:/D:/Projects/make/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/resources/META-INF/log4j-provider.properties
 [java]  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
 [java]     at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
 [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.addShutdownHook(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:151)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.start(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:137)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.initializeShutdownCallbackRegistry(Log4jContextFactory.java:125)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:92)
 [java]     at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:58)
 [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.logging.log4j2.HybrisLog4j2LoggerContextFactory.<init>(HybrisLog4j2LoggerContextFactory.java:22)
 [...]
```

Does anybody know where this come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answear on the expers site:

> Just shut down your Hybris server and delete below 4 files from your
>   **data** folder: *hybristomcat.java.id, hybristomcat.java.pid,
>   hybristomcat.java.status, hybristomcat.lock*
>
> And now restart the server. These 4 files would be created again once
>   server is started and Hybris would map these tomcat server properties
>   with your machine's JVM.

This solution worked for me.